# Best practice for providing storage to guest VMs?

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, centos7

I have the following setup:

- a host machine with CentOS 7 on a 120gb SSD
- a couple debian VMs with KVM running
- 2 1TB HDDs installed and formatted with ext3 connected to host.

so since the guest and host are both on the 120gb SSD, they obviously dont have alot of storage space. my goal is it to be able to use both 1TB HDDs I have to provide storage space that both host and guests can read/write. I looked into the Redhat documentation on how to do that, but as far as I can see, I can only provide space for one VM and that VM has to format the drive once to use it.

my current idea is to create a storage VM that has access to both drives based on the solution above and provides a network drive with both of those drives. I dont know how to do that but some googling should do the work.

Is my idea good? what would be the best way to do something like this? thanks for any answer!

Comment: There's not really a "best practice" as it depends on your needs. Personally I would just run an NFS service on the host. It can access the file system directly, and the guests can mount the file system over NFS. Mirroring those disks may also be beneficial, but again it depends on your requirements.

Comment: I looked up NFS and it seems to be what I'm looking for, thanks for the tip! having backup seems to be beneficial so I'll look into that too. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Nfs is a good point but if you changing your networks(as the result of it - IP addresses) not very frequently. Otherwise you will have to reconfigure nfs sever and clients connecting to it all the time. I do not see any problems with sharing the host folder with guest - the most usual way

Answer (score 0):

NFS is generally the protocol to use to share with UNIX/Linux hosts. Its behavior when the NFS server goes away leaves something to be desired, so don't expect easy recovery with databases.  But it is a decent file share.

Mirror your spindles to tolerate a drive failure. Then export NFS from the VM host/a container/a VM. Or from a separate physical array dedicated to storage.  Each choice has different level of isolation and overhead.

Obviously, test backup restores that meet your recovery objectives. Especially for your host and VM storage currently on a single disk.

Answer (score 0):

Should the storage be shared between the guests? If not use LVM on the 2 1TB drives; both disk as physical volume (pv) in 1 volume group (vg). This way you can create a logical volume (lv) for each guest, add it to its configuration and mount this with in the guest.

If that sounds to complicated, have a look at proxmox as your hypervisor...